# HTML page is blank after using folium to create map

Tags: python, html, pandas, folium

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me in fixing my Python/HTML code. I am trying to plot the locations of volcanoes near Lake Shasta using the folium library in Python and pandas to zip the latitude, longitude, name, and elevation columns from a CSV file. The CSV file is properly formatted as I can access the data (e.g. calculate means). While I managed to create a dataframe, my print out of the HTML code does not yield the desired map. I am using chrome to try and open the file. Below is the code. Any help in resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Kyle

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Volcanoes_USA.csv')
latmean = df['LAT'].mean()
lonmean = df['LON'].mean()

map = folium.Map(location = [latmean, lonmean], zoom_start = 5, tiles = 'Stamen Terrain')

def color(ELEV):
    if ELEV in range(0, 1000):
        col = 'green'
    elif ELEV in range (1001,1999):
        col = 'blue' 
    elif ELEV in range(2000,2999):
        col = 'orange'
    else:
        col = 'red'

for LAT,LON,NAME,ELEV in zip(df['LAT'], df['LON'], df['NAME'], df['ELEV']):
    folium.Marker(location=[LAT, LON], popup = NAME, icon = folium.Icon(color = color(ELEV), icon = 'cloud')).add_to(map)

print(map.save("test6.html"))
```

Comment: Everything looks in order except for the function `color()` .  It never returns a value ie `col`.  That might be the issue

Comment: Thank you for the help! I figured out that folium has updated it's html printouts in v0.4.0 and 0.5.0. Any "  '  " symbols in the data frame text will cause a syntax error, thus a workaround is needed. I'm not sure how to go about doing this as it is a problem with the HTML end of it. As a temporary solution, I've replaced all "  '  " symbols in the data frame with an underscore until a workaround can be figured out. Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, i wonder if you need to escape the single quotes with something?

Comment: I figured it out! For some reason, the HTML file is having trouble reading anything with apostrophes in the name (e.g. Hell's, Bell's , etc...). I went through the data and changed them to underscores for now and the program worked. I guess the old folium had a workaround for the apostrophe but it is now read as a *close bracket* or something of the sort, throwing off the syntax. Awaiting reply from folium team on any way to fix this.

Comment: also, I added a return col

Comment: Someone is having a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376591/why-does-mapping-in-folium-with-over-100-circle-markers-result-in-a-blank-map).  Try `df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.replace("'", "&#39;")`  This will allow the apostrophes to render.

Answer (score 3):

If there are quotes (') in the string, you will get a blank page.

You need to make the following change:

```
popup=folium.Popup(df['NAME'],parse_html=True))
```